# Static метод в kotline

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть метод в java:

```
public static Locale parseStringLocale(String locale) {
    return locale.length() > 2
            ? new Locale(locale.substring(0, 2), locale.substring(3))
            : new Locale(locale);
}
```

При попытке сконвертировать его в kotlin получается нечто подобное:

```
fun parseStringLocale(locale: String): Locale {
    return if (locale.length > 2)
        Locale(locale.substring(0, 2), locale.substring(3))
    else
        Locale(locale)
}
```

Но он уже не static, ему стоит как то приклеить companion object или как можно решить вопрос, для будущего вызова данного метода.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Статические методы в Kotlin задаются через `companion object`

т.е. в вашем случае

```
companion object{
    fun parseStringLocale(locale: String): Locale {
        return if (locale.length > 2)
            Locale(locale.substring(0, 2), locale.substring(3))
        else
            Locale(locale)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Я бы рекомендовал в Kotlin заменять служебные методы (util) на extensions. Модификатор static убрали не для того, чтобы все методы перемещать в компаньон. Я бы сделал так:

```
fun String.toLocale(): Locale {
    //здесь ваша логика, обращайтесь к данному String с помощью this
}
```

Если вы же хотите сделать util класс, можно сделать просто object:

```
object LocaleUtils {

    //fun parseStringLocale...

}
```